# How to import variables from a different function to another?

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to call a variable that is in other function.

Here is my example code

```
#test

def function1():
    var1 = 10


def function2 ():
    print(var1) #How to import var1 on this function?

function1()
function2()
```

Any ideas?

I have tried searching on google but there is no information, and I have tried like calling `var1()` but that only results in an error.